# show hide category based on clicked category angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show and hide subcategory based on the selected category.
both comes dynamic from backend
but something went wrong.
Here is my code:-

```
 <div class="expense-categories">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 category_id" ng-repeat="category in mExpenseCategories">
       <a href="javascript:void()" ng-click="setActiveCategory(category)">
         <div class={{category.class}} ng-class="{active : activeCategory === category}">
           <img src={{category.image}} alt="">
           <p>{{category.name}}</p>
         </div>
       </a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 sub-category-none">
       <ul class="sub-category-menu animated fadeInLeft">
         <li><a class="category-back btn btn-fab btn-inverse btn-raised" href="javascript:void()"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i></a></li>
         <li><a class="well" href="javascript:void()">ab</a></li>
         <li><a class="well" href="javascript:void()">ab</a></li>
         <li><a class="well" href="javascript:void()">ab</a></li>
         <li><a class="well" href="javascript:void()">ab</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Controller code:-

```
$scope.setActiveCategory = function(category) {
  $scope.activeCategory = category;
  $scope.showCategory = category;
  $scope.show = category.id;
  var mySelectedCategory = angular.element(document.querySelector('.category_id'));
  mySelectedCategory.hide();
  mySelectedCategory.addClass('display-category');
  var subCategory = angular.element(document.querySelector('.sub-category-none'));
  subCategory.show();
};

$scope.selectedSubcategory = function() {
  var subCategory = angular.element(document.querySelector('.sub-category-none'));
  subCategory.hide();
  var myCategory = angular.element(document.querySelector('.category_id'));
  myCategory.removeClass("display-category");
};
```

JSON For Category and SubCategory:-

```
[{id: 1, name: "cat_1"},{id: 1, name: "cat_2"}]
```

Comment: send sample Json for mExpenseCategories

Comment: question updated @VenkaTeshuser5397700

Comment: do you handling category and subcategory in separate scope???

Comment: there.......????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition might help "{active : activeCategory.id == category.id}"

```
 <div class={{category.class}} ng-class="{active : activeCategory.id == category.id}">
```

Comment: Thanx  brother:-)